# Simple linear equation using qr.solve gives very off the mark results

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to figure out how to solve a system of linear equations which are approximations (i.e. there is error in the solution, and I want it minimized).

To understand/verify the process, I came up with a simple example: I give a bunch of 5x + 4x^2 + 3x^3 with a 0-5% error in the answer.

```
> a
       [,1]  [,2]    [,3]
  [1,]    1     1       1
  [2,]    2     4       8
  [3,]    3     9      27
[...]
 [98,]   98  9604  941192
 [99,]   99  9801  970299
[100,]  100 10000 1000000

> b
  [1]      12.04      48.17     130.02     269.93     505.75     838.44
  [7]    1202.04    1911.69    2590.51    3381.00    4538.80    5846.19
...
 [97] 2824722.45 2826700.98 3012558.52 2920400.25
```

When I try to solve this using qr.solve,

```
> qr.solve(a,b)
[1] 85.2896286 -0.8924785  3.0482766
```

the results are completely off (want 5, 4, 3). I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Or perhaps my experiment with polynomials is inherently bad? (if so, why?)

Comment: Could you make this example reproducible?

Comment: This word "linear". I do not think it means what you think it means. (y = 5x + 4x^2 + 3x^3 is a polynomial and not linear).

Comment: @mathematical.coffee In this context "linear" refers to linearity *in the parameters*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this problem with an additive error:

```
a <- cbind(1:100, (1:100)^2, (1:100)^3)
set.seed(42)
b <- a %*% (5:3) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1)
qr.solve(a, b)
#         [,1]
#[1,] 4.998209
#[2,] 4.000056
#[3,] 3.000000
```

I can reproduce it with a relative error, but that's not really surprising, since the error is then dominated by the magnitude of the third degree summand:

```
a <- cbind(1:100, (1:100)^2, (1:100)^3)
set.seed(42)
b <- a %*% (5:3) * rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.1)
qr.solve(a, b)
#             [,1]
#[1,] -1686.611970
#[2,]    68.693368
#[3,]     2.481742
```

Note that the third coefficient is about what you expect (even more so in you not-reproducible example).

Comment: I may have been a bit drastic when I added an error. I added a 5% error (i.e. if the real value was 1000 i would randomly add -50..+50 to it, and if it was 10000 I would randomly add -500..+500). I presume that is the problem (which I would have presumed was doable, but guess not).